# Method outlined is POST but is passed as a GET

Tags: java, http, servlets

I'm creating a very simple login page using JSP for the first time and I'm getting an error. I've specified that the form method is POST meaning the data won't be passed within the URL. However it does and the POST function isn't called.  What's more is that the same page is reloaded and if I enter the data in one more time the POST function is then called and it's intended function is carried out. I don't understand.

[Before filling out form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4VKf.png)

[After filling out form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbOQz.png)

HTML Page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  </head>
  <body id="body">

    <div id="main">
      <h1 id="bruh">LOGIN</h1>

      <form action="login" method="POST">
          <input class = "textFields" id="tfUsername" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
          <input class = "textFields" id="tfPassword" type="password" name ="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
      </form>

      <div id="bottom">
        <p class="text">Not a member? Sign up <a href="gsdf" class="text">now</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
package com.jame;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {

        
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException  {
    
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("this is the username: " + username);
        System.out.println("this is the password: " + password);
        
        
        if(username.contentEquals("test") && password.contentEquals("test")) {
            res.sendRedirect("login.html");
            System.out.println("login successful");
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jame.loginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your redirect to a JSP page instead of an HTML file. Hopefully, when your POST request is received by the Servlet, it will redirect you to a JSP page to welcome the user with its username.

Create a JSP Page (**home.jsp**) with the following:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Your App Name</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <center>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      
      <ul>
         <li><p><b>Username: </b>
            <%= request.getParameter("username")%>
         </p></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

In your  Servlet, change the redirect.

Change this:

```
        if(username.contentEquals("test") && password.contentEquals("test")) {
            res.sendRedirect("login.html");
            System.out.println("login successful");
        }
```

to:

```
        if(username.contentEquals("test") && password.contentEquals("test")) {
            res.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
            System.out.println("login successful");
        }
```